# tab (символ табуляции по-контексту) ошибочно переведён как "вкладка"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

```
don't use tabs
```

фраза со страницы [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) переведёна неверно.

На странице [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) фразу:

```
не стоит использовать вкладки
```

следует заменить на:

```
не стоит использовать символы табуляции
```

То есть по смыслу имеется ввиду не графический элемент, а символ Tab ↹, (`\t`).

Comment: Угу, я видел, но всё ленился разыскать оригинал. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Хм, не могу найти этот текст в транзифексе. Переспрошу у админов.

Comment: Спасибо! Исправили!